# python script not launching when put into crontab

Tags: raspbian, linux, python-3, cron

I have two python scripts, flickSwitch.py & measureTemp.py, the first calls the second when a button is pressed. All works fine when run directly from /home/pi.

I put the first script into `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot sudo python3 /home/pi/flickSwitch.py &
```

I can see it launches on reboot by a LED on a tower light flashing red.

But pressing the button now doesn't seem to launch the second script "measureTemp.py".

Any ideas?

Below are the two scripts:
flickSwitch.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import automationhat
import time
import subprocess, os
import signal
#import measureTemp

def towerlight_cleanup():
    automationhat.output.one.off()
    automationhat.output.two.off()
    automationhat.output.three.off()
    automationhat.relay.one.off()

automationhat.output.one.on()
time.sleep(2)
automationhat.output.one.off()

try:

    run = 0
    while True:
        if automationhat.input[0].read() == 1 and run == 0:
            print('switch flicked on')
            print('starting measureTemp.py script')
            run_script = 'python3 /home/pi/measureTemp.py'
            p=subprocess.Popen(run_script, shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
            run=1
            while automationhat.input[0].read() == 1:
                time.sleep(0.01)
        if automationhat.input[0].read() == 0 and run == 1:
            print('switch flicked off')
            print('killing script...')
            run = 0
            towerlight_cleanup()
            os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
            while automationhat.input[0].read() == 0:
                time.sleep(0.01)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    towerlight_cleanup()
    print('keyboard interrupt')
```

measureTemp.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# programme to measure temp of raspberryPi and turn on appropriate LED on tower light.
import os
from time import sleep
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
from gpiozero import OutputDevice
import automationhat


#       DEFINE VARIABLES        #

# Light Tower output pins (BCM pin numbering )
redPin = automationhat.output.one
greenPin = automationhat.output.two
yellowPin = automationhat.output.three
buzPin = automationhat.relay


def measure_temp():
    temp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline()    # reads output of command
    temp, celsius = temp.replace("temp=","").split("'")   # takes the output and slipts it at ' and returns a list of two
    return (temp)


def POT():
    print('commencing POT...')
    leds = [redPin, yellowPin, greenPin]
    for x in range(3):
        for led in leds:
            led.on()
            sleep(0.1)
            led.off()
    print('POT complete...')


def blink_tower_led(led):
    led.on()
    sleep(2)
    led.off()

def main():
    # test all leds in tower light are working:
    POT()
    sleep(2)
    print('tower lights all tested...proceeding to main programme...')

    while True:
        temp = float(measure_temp())
        if temp >= 46:
            print("it's getting hot in here...{}C".format(temp))
            blink_tower_led(redPin)
        elif temp >= 35 <= 45:
            print("it's getting rather warm...{}C".format(temp))
            blink_tower_led(yellowPin)
        else:
            print("it's nice and cool {}C if you don't mind".format(temp))
            blink_tower_led(greenPin)
        sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: How do you know?  The script will not be connected to a display so any screen output will be dumped.

Comment: @joan The second script turns on/off LEDs in the towerlight and they do not turn on/off hence my assumption that the script does not run.

Comment: @joan plus doing a ps -aux | grep measureTemp.py returns nothing.

Comment: `sudo chmod +x /home/pi/measureTemp.py` ,  `which python3` :  `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/measureTemp.py` ,  `Popen("bash -c python3 /home/pi/measureTemp.py", ...)` have you try this ?

Comment: `@reboot sudo python3 /home/pi/flickSwitch.py &>/home/pi/myscript.log &` ... after started , what is the content of this file ? (may contain your error)

Comment: @Ephemeral what does the "bash -c" do?

Comment: this open a new bash shell and execute python3

Comment: @Tullio_IRL, the `-c` flag tells bash that we are passing it a command to execute. For more information, type `bash --help` and look at 6th and 5th lines from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Nice puzzle... You should work toward discovering some more information to narrow this down:

1. You've stated, *"All works fine when run directly from /home/pi"*. From that statement, it would seem that ***something*** is different when `cron` starts your job instead of you (your user id). And indeed it is. Among other things, the [`environment`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm) is different. Once you've read [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm), you will begin to wonder... if `cron`'*s* `PATH` variable is different than the `PATH` set for me as my user id, perhaps the reason things don't work is that the system doesn't know where the programs I'm calling are located. For example, does `cron`'*s* `environment` tell the system where the programs `sudo` and `python3` are located?

   Knowing how to discover what `cron`'*s* `environment` is will help you answer this first question. [Here's one way to discover `cron`'*s* `environment` variables, and therefore its `PATH`.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/WhatIsCronEnvironment.md)

   If you discover a program you're telling `cron` to start is not in `cron`'*s* `PATH`, you could correct that easily by adding the full file specification to the line in your `crontab`.
2. Why have you put the `&` at the end of your `flickSwitch.py` program? AFAIK, all jobs run by `cron` are run in the "background", and so this appears to be redundant - at best. Have you tried eliminating the `&` to see if it makes any difference?
3. Related to the `environment` is the question, "Where does my output go?" And for that matter, where does the system send error messages and get its input? These are called `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (See 1 & 2 for details: [1](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr)). If you launched your program from the command line, the system would know to send any error messages to your terminal. But, if `cron` starts your job, where are those error messages sent?

   There is a *shell trick* you could use to make sure you are informed of any exceptions encountered when `cron` starts your job. You could *redirect* the `stderr` output to a file. In this way, you won't miss any exceptions thrown when `cron` tries to start your job. Here's one way to accomplish this *redirection*:

```
   @reboot /home/pi/myjob >> /home/pi/myjob_errorlog.txt 2>&1
```

There are some more things we could try, but this information will help narrow things down. You can edit your question & add anything useful you learn from 1 - 3 above.